# Using getpts to get selected points

Tags: matlab, select, point

I'm trying to use `getpts` to get the location of the selected points by the user.

I used it as follows:

```
[X,Y] = getpts(imread('xyz.jpg'));
```

But, got the following error:

```
Error using getpts (line 46)
First argument is not a valid handle.

Error in program (line 7)
[X,Y] = getpts(imread('xyz.jpg'));
```

Why is that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getpts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/getpts.html) needs a handle to either a figure or an axes, not a matrix as given by `imread`.

The simple solution is to display the image, then input either `gca` or `gcf` to `getpts`.  Or you can manage handles on your own, but I don't think you wan't to do that.

Or to put it on one line with `imshow`:

```
[X,Y] = getpts(get(imshow('xyz.jpg'),'Parent'));
```